# Cannot get MPMoviePlayerController to return to my TableView

Tags: iphone

I have a table view that has a list videos. When I click on one it uses `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the corresponding video.  I cannot figure out how to have the player return to the list-view when the video finishes or I click on the done button.

I read the documentation and they said there was a
`MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`.
I figure I could have code that would go off when the notification was sent to go back to my list-view, but:

1. I do not understand notifications. Are they like using a delegate for a call back?
2. After I detected the notification, how would I tell the player to go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the MPMoviePlayerViewController then the approach is something like:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentUrl:url];
[myViewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
```

You don't need to worry about the notification then. Once the user clicks done the movie player will go away.